# NFS share permission issue from windows on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, permissions, windows-7, nfs

I've create one share on ubuntu 14.04 machine and set a `/etc/export` file as below:

```
/Myshare        *(rw,sync,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

Now issue is that, If I create file on ubuntu machine then open on windows but unable to same it and If I create file from windows and open on ubuntu then it will open on readonly mode/showing `Lock` icon.

If I create file from in windows then

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 4294967294 4294967294      12 Sep  7 16:33 demo.txt
```

If I create file from in ubuntu then

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 admin      admin            7 Sep  7 16:33 demo1.txt(try to open from windows)
-rw-rw-r--  1 admin      admin            7 Sep  7 16:33 demo1.txt~
```

Have you any idea about same ???

Answer (score 1):

Couple things. The `*` is probably fine but you may want to be a little more explicit and do something like `192.168.0.0/24`.

I believe `sync` is the default so you could leave it out. You may want to try adding the `no_root_squash` command to just map all share clients to root access. Should fix your issue.